# virtual host setup in xampp, won7

Tags: apache, webserver, xampp

I install XAMPP(OS : win 7 ) in D drive. Document root is D:/xampp/htdocs
When I open localhost/xampp/ then it open . No problem

I create virtual host zf2.local as bellow and it's working fine.

```
<VirtualHost zf2.local:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/WORK/zend/public"
    ServerName zf2.local
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I configure like bellow then it's show forbiden

```
<VirtualHost zf2.local:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/WORK/zend/public"
    ServerName zf2.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Actually I want to set document root outside the htdocs & both should work means localhost as well as virtual host. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" # change this line with your htdocs folder
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
        <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Read [this article](http://austin.passy.co/2012/setting-up-virtual-hosts-wordpress-multisite-with-xampp-on-windows-7/) for further help

Comment: my default document root is D:/xampp/htdocs/ . When I put my folders under it then it's working fine but when I put my folder out side the D:/xampp/htdocs/ it's not working. I want to to put vhost folder in another drive

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
<Directory "D:/WORK/zend/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

OR

```
<Directory "D:/WORK/zend/public">
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```